# How to install MS SQL Management Srudio for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-management-studio

I have downloade `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe` file, but when I run it, it starts global SQL server 2008 installer where I can't find any signs of Management Studio.

Comment: Did you try to install it?

Answer (score 1):

It just looks like the full SQL installer.

Just use it and you'll find that only the Management Utilities are selectable for install.